# How to make a shuffle method in a linked list

Tags: java

I am trying to make a shuffle method in my LinkedList. Currently, my method of shuffling is to generate a random number, n, between 1 to 10, and take the n(th) number of card and move it to the front. Then it will loop in a random amount of time. However, my current code does not seem to work as the card it takes just get removed instead of bringing it to the front.

```
public void shuffle() {
        Node current = head;
        int randomX = (int) (Math.random() * 10 + 1);
        for (int x = 0; x < randomX; x++) {
            int randomY = (int) (Math.random() * 10 + 1);
            for (int y = 0; y < randomY; y++) {
                if (current.getNext() != null) {
                    current = current.getNext();
                    System.out.println("Yup");
                    System.out.println(current);
                    System.out.println(y);
                } 
                else {
                    current = head;
                    System.out.println("nope");
                    current = current.getNext();

                }

                if (current.getPrevious() != null){
                    current.getPrevious().setNext(current.getNext());
                    head.setPrevious(current);
                    current.setPrevious(head);

                }
                head = current;
            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: Are you required to use a Linked list?

Comment: Yes, I have to use a linked list for this

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle

Comment: I suggest to take a look at java.util.Collections.shuffle implementation

Comment: I am not able to use collections shuffle as it is actually a self-implemented doubly linked list.

Comment: @DarrylSohSoonYong I think he meant to look at the code and write your own based on that implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that when you find the node you are looking for that you set its *previous node's next* to its next AND you set *the node's next previous* to its previous

```
Node temp = head;
int randomX = (int) (Math.random() * 10 + 1);

//simply go until the randomX
while(randomX-- > 0 && temp.getNext() != null)
    temp = temp.getNext();

//remove the Nth node from the list
temp.getPrevious().setNext(temp.getNext());

if(temp.getNext() != null)
    temp.getNext().setPrevious(temp.getPrevious());

//set it to point to the head
temp.setNext(head);
temp.setPrevious(null);

//now set the Head to the Nth node we found
head = temp;
```

Comment: Thank you for your code, this works for what I am trying to do, however since I am using a DoublyLinkedList I had to make some changes to it.

Answer (score 0):

It look like your `move the randomly chosen node to head` is misplaced. It should be **outside** the loop that chooses the one to move.

A few comments would have made this obvious.

```
public void shuffle() {
    Node current = head;
    // How many times to shuffle.
    int randomX = (int) (Math.random() * 10 + 1);
    // Move random node to head random number of times.
    for (int x = 0; x < randomX; x++) {
        // Pick the one to move.
        int randomY = (int) (Math.random() * 10 + 1);
        // Go find it.
        for (int y = 0; y < randomY; y++) {
            if (current.getNext() != null) {
                current = current.getNext();
                System.out.println("Yup");
                System.out.println(current);
                System.out.println(y);
            } else {
                // Hit end of list - go back to start.
                current = head;
                System.out.println("nope");
                current = current.getNext();

            }
        }
        // Bring the chosen one to `head` - **** I moved this OUTSIDE the loop above.
        if (current.getPrevious() != null) {
            current.getPrevious().setNext(current.getNext());
            head.setPrevious(current);
            current.setPrevious(head);

        }
        head = current;
    }
}
```